# conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a conda environmet in google colab notebook. I succesfully installed conda with the following comannd

> !wget -c
>   https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
>
> !chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
>
> !bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

Default python which is using by system is now **Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.**

I am trying to create an environment in conda by **conda env create -f environment.yml**

Every package got successfully installed but the problem now is that I am not able to activate this environment.
I tried **source activate myenv**. but it also didn't worked.

After **conda env list** command I got two environments

**base                  *  /usr/local**

**myenv                  /usr/local/envs/myenv**

Can anyone please help me how can I switch on to "myenv" environment?
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: I don't think the running instance can normally update online to use the environment, you'd typically start Jupyter Notebook after switching to an environment when working locally at least. I guess the question generalizes to "can you use conda environment export files in Google Colab"

Comment: Hello @aryan. Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar issue trying to run rlgarage in google colab

Comment: @matanster Thankyou for your reply. Yeah, we can do it locally but I think google collab doesn't allow to switch to any other conda environment.

Comment: @shadi, I couldnt able to create a conda enviornment, rather I installed all my required libraries using pip.

Comment: Any update on this, I'd like to create a conda env on Google collab

Comment: I am trying to get this working also. I can get !source activate myenv to run, but it only runs while the cell is processing the ! command. `!conda create --name test37 python=3.7` then `!source activate test37 && conda list !conda list` Once the ! command is finished, the next command reverts back to the original env. I suspect the ! command opens a temporary shell, runs the command, then closes...

Comment: Posted a more complete answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/how-to-setup-and-run-conda-on-google-colab/75979#75979

Comment: Nice tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522

Answer (score 17):

You can activate and run a new conda environment in Google Colab by using the magic %%bash command:

```
%%bash
source activate myenv

python
import sys
# some simple python commands
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
print(sys.path)

print("Python version")
print(sys.version)
```

Also including a few other commands I needed to run to get my environment setup completely:

```
!conda update conda -y -q
!source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
!conda init 
!conda install -n root _license -y -q
```

Comment: Did you run the 'other' commands before or after the bash script? Also, do they need to be run in the created environment, or on the default one?

Comment: @EmmanuelB,  I ran the 4 other commands first, from the default environment

Answer (score 10):

## a quick fix

put `!source activate myenv &&` before all your bash commands

```
!source activate myenv && <COMMAND1>
```

For example

```
!source activate myenv && conda env list
```

> base    /usr/local

> myenv * /usr/local/envs/myenv

## justification:

Well we have to put `!` in front of your bash commands anyway...
But I would love to know a better way.

Answer (score 6):

I installed conda package in `/usr/local` and work fine

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

then you can install any package you want

```
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local -c pytorch -c tensorcomp tensor_comprehensions
```

Comment: I think this process uses the base environment, which is the default when you log in. The problem is creating a new conda environment and then activating that environment so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick fix would be to run the command:

```
source PATH/to/activate env_name
```

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9539

Comment: this solution does not persist across the cells of Colab, the environment returns to the default