# Create conda environment using yml file in Google Colab

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory

I have a [environment.yml](https://github.com/ChenyangLEI/polarization-reflection-removal/blob/master/environment.yml) file which i used as follows on my local system,

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

But I have now shifted to Google Colab and installed Conda into it using [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522).

How can I now create a new conda environment inside Colab using the .yml file as I used to do on my local system?

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62346425/1218179

Comment: can refer to this article also: https://medium.com/@shibugarg0303/run-entire-python-project-on-google-colab-10de1871c9a5