# BeautifulSoup getting href of a list - need to simplify the script - in order to run in Colab

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I have the following soup:

[image]

next ... From this I want to extract the href, "some_url"
this I want to extract the href, "some_url"
and the whole list of the pages that are listed on this page:

```
https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/laa.html
```

**note**: there are a whole lot of links to sub-pages: which i need to parse. at the moment: getting all the data out it : -dioceses -Urls -description -contact-data -etc. etx.

the following is one way of getting that information, in an async fashion (should work on Colab notebooks). I got thet dioceses urls from a different part of the site (Structured view - World Regions). I would expect the dioceses count there to match the count from the letters list.

```
from httpx import Client, AsyncClient, Limits
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

big_df_list = []

def all_dioceses():
    dioceses = []
    root_links = [f'https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/qview{x}.html' for x in range(1, 8)]
    with Client(headers=headers, timeout=60.0, follow_redirects=True) as client:
        for x in root_links:
            r = client.get(x)
            soup = bs(r.text)
            soup.select_one('ul#menu2').decompose()
            for link in soup.select('ul > li > a'):
                dioceses.append('https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/' + link.get('href'))
    return dioceses
# print(all_dioceses())

async def get_diocese_info(url):
    async with AsyncClient(headers=headers, timeout=60.0, follow_redirects=True) as client:
        try:
            r = await client.get(url)
            soup = bs(r.text)
            d_name = soup.select_one('h1[align="center"]').get_text(strip=True)
            info_table = soup.select_one('div[id="d1"] > table')
            d_bishops = ' | '.join([x.get_text(strip=True) for x in info_table.select('td')[0].select('li')])
            d_extra_info = ' | '.join([x.get_text(strip=True) for x in info_table.select('td')[1].select('li')])
            big_df_list.append((d_name, d_bishops, d_extra_info, url))
            print('done', d_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(url, e)

async def scrape_dioceses():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    tasks = asyncio.Queue()
    for x in all_dioceses():
        tasks.put_nowait(get_diocese_info(x))

    async def worker():
        while not tasks.empty():
            await tasks.get_nowait()
            
    await asyncio.gather(*[worker() for _ in range(100)])
    end_time = datetime.now()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    print('diocese scraping took', duration)

asyncio.run(scrape_dioceses())
df = pd.DataFrame(big_df_list, columns = ['Name', 'Bishops', 'Info', 'Url'])
print(df)
```

this should lead to the following resuts:

```
done Eparchy of Mississauga (Syro-Malabar)
done Eparchy of Mar Addai of Toronto (Chaldean)
done Eparchy of Saint-Sauveur de Montr�al (Melkite Greek)
done Diocese of Calgary
done Archdiocese of Winnipeg
[...]
diocese scraping took 0:03:02.366096

Name    Bishops Info    Url
0   Eparchy of Mississauga (Syro-Malabar)   JoseKalluvelil, Bishop  Type of Jurisdiction: Eparchy | Elevated:22 December2018 | Immediately Subject to the Holy See | Syro-Malabar Catholic Church of the Chaldean Tradition | Country:Canada | Mailing Address: Syro-Malabar Apostolic Exarchate, 6630 Turner Valley Rd., Mississauga, ON L5V 2P1, Canada | Telephone: (905)858-8200 | Fax: 858-8208    https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dmism.html
1   Eparchy of Mar Addai of Toronto (Chaldean)  Robert SaeedJarjis, Bishop | Bawai (Ashur)Soro, Bishop Emeritus Type of Jurisdiction: Eparchy | Erected:10 June2011 | Immediately Subject to the Holy See | Chaldean Catholic Church of the Chaldean Tradition | Country:Canada | Conference Region:Ontario | Mailing Address: 2 High Meadow Place, Toronto, ON M9L 2Z5, Canada | Telephone: (416)746-5816 | Fax: 746-5850  https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dtoch.html
2   Eparchy of Saint-Sauveur de Montr�al (Melkite Greek)    MiladJawish, B.S., Bishop   Type of Jurisdiction: Eparchy | Elevated:1 September1984 | Immediately Subject to the Holy See | Melkite Greek Catholic Church of the Byzantine Tradition | Country:Canada | Conference Region:Quebec | Web Site:http://www.melkite.com/ | Mailing Address: 10025 boul. de l'Arcadie, Montreal, QC H4N 2S1, Canada | Telephone: (514)272.6430 | Fax: 202.1274   https://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dmome.html
```

**note** - it is for me impossible to run this on collab - how to simplify this in order to run this code in collab!?

well - i get errors - i get back this  when running this in the collab:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64bb145c85bf> in <module>
----> 1 from httpx import Client, AsyncClient, Limits
      2 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import re
      5 from datetime import datetime
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httpx'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**note** - it is for me impossible to run this on collab - how to simplify this in order to run this code in collab!?

Mauro Martins mentioned to run this - but wait; i am not a pro user on collab-. so the question is: how to simplify this that i can run it on colab - on a ordinary collab account

```
!pip install httpx nest_asyncio

Try running this code before your script.
```

Many thanks for the quick reply. Awesome. i understand your approach: but i need a pro account on colab - note: i do not have this . So the question is: Can i simplify the script so that it would run on a general collab account - without any issues

many thanks - dear Mauro Martins Junior - it helps - this code helped.:

```
!pip install httpx nest_asyncio
```

**note:**

[image]

update: thanks to Mauro Martin i have learned to update plugins to colab:

**How do I install Python packages in Google's Colab?**

[How do I install Python packages in Google's Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab)

> In a project, I have e.g. two different packages, How can I use the
> setup.py to install these two packages in the Google's Colab, so that
> I can import the packages?

**see the answer**:

> you can use !setup.py install to do that. Colab is just like a Jupyter
> notebook. Therefore, we can use the ! operator here to install any
> package in Colab. What ! actually does is, it tells the notebook cell
> that this line is not a Python code, its a command line script. So, to
> run any command line script in Colab, just add a ! preceding the line.
> For example: !pip install tensorflow. This will treat that line (here
> pip install tensorflow) as a command prompt line and not some Python
> code. However, if you do this without adding the ! preceding the line,
> it'll throw up an error saying "invalid syntax". But keep in mind that
> you'll have to upload the setup.py file to your drive before doing
> this (preferably into the same folder where your notebook is).

and also the **conda environment:**

**conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]**
[conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory)

> I am trying to create a conda environmet in google colab notebook. I
> succesfully installed conda with the following comannd

conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]
[conda environment in google colab [google-colaboratory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory)
I am trying to create a conda environmet in google colab notebook. I succesfully installed conda with the following comannd

I am trying to create a conda environmet in google colab notebook. I succesfully installed conda with the following comannd

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
```

Default python which is using by system is now Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

I am trying to create an environment in conda by conda env create -f environment.yml

Every package got successfully installed but the problem now is that I am not able to activate this environment. I tried source activate myenv. but it also didn't worked.

After conda env list command I got two environments

```
base * /usr/local

myenv /usr/local/envs/myenv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that some libs are missing. I tried to run here on colabs and after running the command below, it worked fine.

`!pip install httpx nest_asyncio`

Try running this code before your script.

Note that the exclamation point is part of the command.

Comment: good day dear Mauro Martins Many thanks for the quick reply. Awesome.  i understand your approach: but i need a pro account on colab - note: i do not have this . So the question is: Can i simplify the script so that it would run on a general collab account - without any issues

Comment: Hello there. I ran it on a common account. Without the benefits of the paid account.

Comment: hello dear Mauro Martins Junior - many thanks i will try it out. I will try it out immidiately

Comment: hello dear Mauro - many many thanks for all: one question where does the program - where does colab store the data!?

Comment: hello thanne.. I`m not sure if a undestand your question.. Can you give me more details about it?