How to install dependencies in conda environment in Google colab
I am new to Python. For analyzing the single-cell multiomics datasets, I have purchased Google Colab Pro. Because the dataset is large, the model requires GPU and conda environment for the analysis. I have installed the miniconda by using the following command,
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

Except Python 3.8.1 I couldn't install the other dependencies in the conda environment. I have used the following code to install python,
!conda create -n scMDC python=3.8.1 --solver classic -y

The other dependencies are:
Python 3.8.1

Pytorch 1.6.0

Scanpy 1.6.0

SKlearn 0.22.1

Numpy 1.18.1

h5py 2.9.0  

I have tried the following code for running the other dependencies, but the code returned the error messages.
!conda install -n scMDC -c conda-forge pytorch==1.6.0 scanpy==1.6.0 scikit-learn==0.22.1 numpy==1.18.1 h5py==2.9.0 --solver classic -y

The model which I am trying to run is scMDC (https://github.com/xianglin226/scMDC).
Google colab pro providing only 100 computing units. But everytime I am wasting the computing units, just by running the wrong codes again and again. So kindly provide your suggestions to solve this matter.

Refer this enter link description here

can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031430/conda-environment-in-google-colab-google-colaboratory?noredirect=1&lq=1 question, similar to it.
